# How to write LINQ for LEFT JOIN a table which is GROUP BY?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a SQL Server query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ENotes en LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ENoteId, ReadByUId, [Read]
    FROM [ENotesReadBies]
    WHERE ReadByUId = 1173 AND [Read] = 1
    GROUP BY ENoteId, ReadByUId, [Read]
) A ON (en.ENoteId = A.ENoteId)
```

How to write a LINQ for it? I know I can left join like this:

```
from x in _context.ENotes
join erb in _context.ENotesReadBies on x.ENoteId equals erb.ENoteId
into tempReadBy
from rb in tempReadBy.Where(x => x.ReadByUId == 1173 && x.Read == true).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But this does not have the GROUP BY.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using .net core 3?

Answer (score 1):

Lets do that this way:

```
var groupPart = from erb in _context.ENotesReadBies
            where erb.ReadByUId == 1173 && erb.Read
            group erb by new { erb.ENoteId, erb.ReadByUId, erb.Read } into grouped
            select new
            {
                grouped.Key.ENoteId,
                grouped.Key.ReadByUId,
                grouped.Key.Read
            };

var result = from e in _context.ENotes
            join g in groupPart
            on e.ENoteId equals g.ENoteId into gJ
            from g in gJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                ENote = e,
                g.ENoteId,
                g.ReadByUId,
                g.Read
            };

var materializedResult = result.ToList();
```

If you run this code and profile its generated sql query you'll get:

```
SELECT [e].[ENoteId], [e].[Name], [t].[ENoteId], [t].[ReadByUId], [t].[Read]
FROM [ENotes] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [e0].[ENoteId], [e0].[ReadByUId], [e0].[Read]
    FROM [ENotesReadBies] AS [e0]
    WHERE ([e0].[ReadByUId] = CAST(1173 AS bigint)) AND ([e0].[Read] = CAST(1 AS bit))
    GROUP BY [e0].[ENoteId], [e0].[ReadByUId], [e0].[Read]
) AS [t] ON [e].[ENoteId] = [t].[ENoteId]
```

that's the same as what you want ;)